# Help to Read exception.log in Magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.8

What is the problem? Please help me. And possible ways to fix it.

We are getting errors on the second stage of Checkout "Payment & Review" when placing an order.

## Exception.log error

```
[2017-09-10 13:12:09] main.CRITICAL: LogicException: Property "TriggerReload" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface". in /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100

Stack trace:
#0 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php(59): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->findAccessorMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), 'TriggerReload', 'getTriggerReloa...', 'isTriggerReload')

#1 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(158): Magento\Framework\Reflection\NameFinder->getGetterMethodName(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\ClassReflection), 'TriggerReload')

#2 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(322): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->_createFromArray('Magento\\Quote\\A...', Array)

#3 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php(119): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->convertValue(Array, 'Magento\\Quote\\A...')

#4 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(101): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor->process('Amasty\\Checkout...', 'savePaymentInfo...', Array)

#5 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(299): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()

#6 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(216): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()

#7 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#8 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

#9 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Webapi\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')

#10 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#11 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#12 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

#13 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#14 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

#15 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))

#16 {main}

Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-59b53a2922b3a; Message: Property "TriggerReload" does not have corresponding setter in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface". in /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195

Stack trace:

#0 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(LogicException))

#1 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(219): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(LogicException))

#2 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#3 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

#4 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Webapi\\...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')

#5 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#6 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#7 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

#8 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#9 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()

#10 /home/97276-75255.cloudwaysapps.com/ktmetqffmk/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))

#11 {main} [] []
```

Comment: have you resolved this issue ?